# How to get Wechat authorization token?

Tags: android, wechat

Target: get token which I need to send to the app server

Problem: registered returns true, requests done returns true, but `onReq` and `onResp`did not get called. Here is the code:

```
public class WeChatActivity extends Activity implements IWXAPIEventHandler {

    private static final String APP_ID = ;
    private IWXAPI api;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

        api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(this, APP_ID, true);
        api.handleIntent(getIntent(), this);

        regToWx();
        getAuthToken();
    }

    private void regToWx() {

        api.handleIntent(getIntent(), this);
        boolean registered = api.registerApp(APP_ID);

        L.e(this, "registered: " + registered);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        setIntent(intent);
        api.handleIntent(intent, this);
    }

    public void getAuthToken() {
        SendAuth.Req req = new SendAuth.Req();
        req.scope = "post_timeline";
        req.state = "none";

        boolean requestDone = api.sendReq(req);
        L.e(this, "request done: " + requestDone);

        SendAuth.Resp resp = new SendAuth.Resp();
        requestDone = api.sendResp(resp);
        L.e(this, "request done: " + requestDone);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReq(BaseReq baseReq) {
        L.e(this, "scope: " + ((SendAuth.Req) baseReq).scope);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResp(BaseResp baseResp) {
        L.e(this, "token: " + ((SendAuth.Resp) baseResp).token);
    }
}
```

Log cat output:

```
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10﹕ check signature:308202eb30820254a003020...
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10﹕ pass
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10﹕ register app cn.wegazine.wegazine
D/MicroMsg.SDK.MMessage﹕ send mm message, intent=Intent { act=com.tencent.mm.plugin.openapi.Intent.ACTION_HANDLE_APP_REGISTER (has extras) }, perm=com.tencent.mm.permission.MM_MESSAGE
E/WeChatActivity﹕ registered: true
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10﹕ check signature:308202eb30820...
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10﹕ pass
D/MicroMsg.SDK.MMessageAct﹕ send mm message, intent=Intent { flg=0x18000000 cmp=com.tencent.mm/.plugin.base.stub.WXEntryActivity (has extras) }
E/WeChatActivity﹕ request done: true
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10﹕ check signature:308202eb30820...
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10﹕ pass
D/MicroMsg.SDK.MMessageAct﹕ send mm message, intent=Intent { flg=0x18000000 cmp=com.tencent.mm/.plugin.base.stub.WXEntryActivity (has extras) }
E/WeChatActivity﹕ request done: true
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of LogCat ?

Comment: Did you figure out the answer @Sinigami? I'm trying to do the same thing and have similar issues.

Comment: @iamronak No, I left this.

Comment: Hey, Facing the same issue. Please help me to get out of this:(

Answer (score 4):

I've face the same problem and solved with two steps.

First check if you've successfully jumped to the wechat app and authorized.
If not, check if you're using the same signing key that you signed to wechat.
(ex. if you signed with the release key and compile with debug key, then wechat app won't open)

Second, by [wechat document](https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showdocument?action=dir_list&t=resource/res_list&verify=1&id=1417751808&token=&lang=en), the class name should be **WXEntryActivity** and should be put under a package named wxapi under **the package with the name you registered at wechat**.

Example in the document: If you register with *"net.sourceforge.simcpux"*, the project structure should look like this

[image]

Also, add `api.HandleIntent(getIntent(), this)` after `sendReq` and `sendResp`

Not sure if the classname is neccessary, but I'm sure you can call `sendReq` in other class and process response with **WXEntryActivity**

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue! Edwards answer helped a lot.

> WxEntryActivity needs to be in the package with the name you registered at wechat!

Especially when you have multiple build variants (debug, release):
[Wechat login - do not receive token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580463/wechat-login-do-not-receive-token/48585533#48585533)

Answer (score -2):

`onReq` and `onResp` will be called in `WXEntryActivity.java` within [JAVA reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Suppose package name `io.github.you`

You should create a directory named `wxapi`,then create a `WXEntryActivity.java`

You get `io.github.you.wxapi.WXEntryActivity.java`

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
    android:name=".wxapi.WXEntryActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_wxentry"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
```

In `WXEntryActivity.java`

```
public class WXEntryActivity implements IWXAPIEventHandler{

@Override
public void onReq(BaseReq arg0) {
    SendAuth.Resp r = (SendAuth.Resp)resp;
    String code = r.code;

}

@Override
public void onResp(BaseResp arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thank for your answer, I did as you say, but problem still there. Possible reason in that: "api.handleIntent(getIntent(), this)" returs false;