# Wechat login - do not receive token

Tags: android, wechat

I just followed all the stuff which are mentioned in this [example](https://github.com/aaronbruckner/wechatAndroidLoginDemo) from Aaron Bruckner. Tried out with and without the boolean flag for enabling the `checkSignature`.

init API:

```
api = WXAPIFactory.createWXAPI(getContext(), WXEntryActivity.APP_ID,
            true);
```

send register:

```
api.registerApp(WXEntryActivity.APP_ID);
```

send login:

```
SendAuth.Req req = new SendAuth.Req();
      req.scope = "snsapi_userinfo";
      req.state = "none";
      api.sendReq(req);
```

When trying to login i get the confirmation screen from wechat. When hitting "Confirm Login" i get redirected to my app but nothing happens.

[image]

The `WXEntryActivity.class` is not called - so i dont receive any token to proceed with my authentification.

the Logs when signature is set to `false`:

```
D/MicroMsg.PaySdk.WXFactory: createWXAPI, appId = wx41XXXXXXXXX41, checkSignature = false
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10: <init>, appId = wx41XXXXXXXXX41, checkSignature = false
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXMsgImplComm: ignore wechat app signature validation
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10: registerApp, appId = wx41XXXXXXXXX41
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10: registerApp, appId = wx41XXXXXXXXX41
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10: register app com.my.packagename.debug
D/MicroMsg.SDK.MMessage: send mm message, intent=Intent { act=com.tencent.mm.plugin.openapi.Intent.ACTION_HANDLE_APP_REGISTER (has extras) }, perm=co
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXMsgImplComm: ignore wechat app signature validation
I/MicroMsg.SDK.WXApiImplV10: sendReq, req type = 1
D/MicroMsg.SDK.MMessageAct: send, targetPkgName = com.tencent.mm, targetClassName = com.tencent.mm.plugin.base.stub.WXEntryActivity
D/MicroMsg.SDK.MMessageAct: send mm message, intent=Intent { flg=0x18000000 cmp=com.tencent.mm/.plugin.base.stub.WXEntryActivity (has extras) }
```

The Logs when signature is `true` are basically the same except:

```
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXMsgImplComm: check signature:3XXXXXXXXX02eb30820254a00302010202XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
D/MicroMsg.SDK.WXMsgImplComm: pass
```

I have the correct Application-Signature MD5 without `:` added to the Wechat-Dev-Console as well as the packageName `com.my.packaname.debug` as i am using my debug.keystore to sign my debug version. 
`WXEntryActivity` is inside my `com.my.packagename.wxapi` and is registered in my `AndroidManifest.xml` with the `exported` flag.
Also i added a rule to `proguard-rules.pro` to be safe:

```
 -keep class com.tencent.mm.sdk.** {
      *;
  }
```

Just can not figure out why the `onCreate` and `onResp` of the `WxEntryActivity` is not getting called to get the token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution found:**

Problem was caused by the package-name.

As am using two build variants **release** & **debug**, 
I expected the packagename to be `com.my.packagename.debug` for my debug-build (which is setup in `build.gradle`) So in the Admin-Center of Wechat i used `com.my.packagename.debug`.
Problem is that the `WxEntryActivity` is called via reflection and my `WxEntryActivity` is located in my `com.my.packagename.wxapi`.

Therefore the class couldnt be found and needs to be put into a "manual" package `.debug.wxapi`.

So you need two Activities located in two different packages when using release and debug.

Comment: It's  `WXEntryActivity` not `WxEntryActivity` see sepc: https://open.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/showdocument?action=dir_list&t=resource/res_list&verify=1&id=1417751808&token=&lang=en

Comment: @Maxi so I need to add copy of same class twice in two different folders?

Comment: @Rameshbabu yes you need to have the Activity in debug and main folder